# TensorFlow Keras Optimise prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm Using tensorflow and keras to predict handwrting digits. For training I'm using nmist dataset.
the accuracy is about 98.8% after training. but sometimes in test its confuse between 4 and 9 , 7 and 3, i'm alerady optimize the image input with opencv, like remove noise, rescale, threshold etc.
**What should i do next to improved this prdiction accuracy?**

My plan is add more sample, and resize the sample image from 28x28 to 56x56.
**Will this affect accuracy?**

This my model for training:

```py
epoc=15, batch size=64

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    # add Convolutional layers
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))    
    model.add(Flatten())
    # Densely connected layers
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

    # output layer
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    # compile with adam optimizer & categorical_crossentropy loss function
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Comment: how much data you used to train.? How much for validation.? Have you done cross-validation.?

Comment: nmints dataset is 60000 train data and 10000 for validation. Not yet, i will try with kfold, thx for the suggestion

Comment: I also recommend to use augmentation with Keras ImageGenerator. It will help the model to generalize better

Comment: I already used  :  it,train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=5,
        width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1,
        shear_range=0.1,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=False,
        fill_mode='nearest').  the parametr size is small because the size is only 28x28, it will messup the digit

Comment: Are you sure the model is not overfitting.?

Comment: i though so, i try to train with 300.000 sample .but return with same result , maybe i will look for that. do you know how to avoid over fitting?  thx in advance

Comment: what is your train and valid accuracies respectively.?

Comment: train accuracy with 300k sample is 0,9996 and tes is 0.97

Comment: So, if there is no potential data leakage from your train to validation set and the test images are similar to the ones the model trained on, the model have to work good.

Comment: after using cross validation and few more tweak, is increasing accuracy or the real handwriting ,  thank you @Sreeram TP

Comment: Nice to hear it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add regularization:

```py
def conv2d_bn(x,
              units,
              kernel_size=(3, 3),
              activation='relu',
              dropout=.5):
    y = Dropout(x)
    y = Conv2D(units, kernel_size=kernel_size, use_bias=False)(y)
    y = BatchNormalization(y)
    y = Activation(activation)(y)

    return y

def build_model(..., dropout=.5):
    x = Input(shape=[...])
    y = conv2d_bn(x, 32)
    y = MaxPooling2D(y)
    ...
    y = Dropout(dropout)(y)
    y = Dense(10, activation='softmax')

    model = Model(x, y)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

---

You can tweak the class weights to force the model to pay more attention to classes 3, 4, 7 and 9 during training:

```py
model.fit(..., class_weights={0: 1, 1: 1, 2:1, 3:2, 4:2, 5:1, 6:1, 7:2, 8:1, 9:2})
```

---

If you have some time to burn, you can also try to *grid* or *random-search* the models hyperparameters. Something in the lines:

```py
def build(conv_layers, dense_layers, dense_units, activation, dropout):
    y = x = Input(shape=[...])

    kernels = 32
    kernel_size = (2, 2)

    for i in range(conv_layers):
        y = conv2d_bn(y, kernel_size, kernels, activation, dropout)

        if i % 2 == 0:  # or 3 or 4.
            y = MaxPooling2D(y)
            kernels *= 2
            kernel_size = tuple(k+1 for k in kernel_size)

    y = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(y)

    for i in range(dense_layers):
        y = Dropout(dropout)(y)
        y = Dense(dense_units)(y)

    y = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(y)


model = KerasClassifier(build_model,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_split=validation_split,
                        verbose=0,
                        ...)
params = dict(conv_layers=[2, 3, 4],
              dense_layers=[0, 1],
              activation=['relu', 'selu'],
              dropout=[.2, .3, .5],
              callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10,
                                                 restore_best_weights=True)])

grid = GridSearchCV(model, params,
                    scoring='balanced_accuracy_score',
                    verbose=2,
                    n_jobs=1)
```

Now, combining hyperparams searching with the `NumpyArrayIterator` is a little tricky, because the latter assumes we have all training samples (and targets) at hand before the training steps. It's still doable, though:

```py
g = ImageDataGenerator(...)
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3)
results = dict(params=[], valid_score=[])

for params in ParameterGrid(params):
    fold_scores = []

    for t, v in cv.split(train_data, train_labels):
        train = g.flow(train_data[t], train_labels[t], subset='training')
        nn_valid = g.flow(train_data[t], train_labels[t], subset='validation')
        fold_valid = g.flow(train_data[v], train_labels[v])

        nn = build_model(**params)
        nn.fit_generator(train, validation_data=nn_valid, ...)

        probabilities = nn.predict_generator(fold_valid, steps=...)
        p = np.argmax(probabilities, axis=1)

        fold_scores += [metrics.accuracy_score(valid.classes_, p)]

    results['params'] += [params]
    results['valid_score'] += [fold_scores]

best_ix = np.argmax(np.mean(results['valid_score'], axis=1))
best_params = results['params'][best_ix]

nn = build_model(**best_params)
nn.fit_generator(...)
```